# Regex that catches comments outside quotes

Tags: java, regex, parsing

I'm trying to erase comments of the form (`/* comment*/`) from a given line but I do not want to delete comments that are inside quotes.  For example if I have the following line:

```
(this /* is "dd" a*/ line "we are /* inside a*/ quote" end of /* the line*/)
```

I'm looking for the right regex (with the help of replace all method) in order to get the following result:

```
(this  line "we are /* inside a*/ quote" end of )
```

I know little about regex – help would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: I don't think regex (alone) is the right tool for the job.

Comment: do you have any suggestions?

Comment: Use a proper parser generator and specify this as a grammar.

Comment: @aioobe Well, a parser will use a regex-based lexer to tokenize the source, including delimiting and ignoring comments. So yes, it is the right tool for the job.

Comment: That's why I said *alone*.

Comment: @aioobe Once the regex has done its job, there's nothing for the parser to do (at least, as far as this question is concerned). Removing comments is not a job for a parser.

Comment: @Sneftel: Identifying comment delimiters that aren't enclosed in string literals is precisely what you need the parser for.  The equivalent regex (if such a thing is even possible) would be huge, ugly, and impossible to maintain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Java you can use this regex:

```
str = str.replaceAll("(?=(?:(?:[^\"]*\"){2})*[^\"]*$)/\\*.*?\\*/", "");
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/aX2jJ2/1)

This regex will find commented block if those are outside double quotes by using a lookahead to make sure there are even number of quotes before commented block.

Comment: So you're saying those unescaped `"` are not going to trigger a syntax error? I really doubt that.

Comment: Yes this regex deals with unescaped `"` only at present in code of course it should be `\"` (fixed). Thanks!

Comment: @anubhava this regex is good but it did not work on the following string :                     `/*"*/ "hi /*" /*"*/` , a help would be appreciated.

Comment: Besides regex method has limitation to work only when `'` are balanced and unescaped. For edge cases like that build a parser.

Comment: i have built a pareser and it worked, perfectly. thanks for the clarification